# Removing multiple spaces from starting of every line in a file in tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to remove the spaces from the starting of each and line of a file
so used this

```
set fp [open "test_one.tcl" r]
set file_data [read $fp]
set lines [split $file_data "\n"]
regsub -all {^\s+} $lines ""
```

after running this all the lines of the file 'test_one.tcl' gets into a list named lines but I'm unable to remove the spaces in the start.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splitting by newlines, you can apply newline sensitive `regsub` command.

```
% set fp [open "test_one.tcl" r]
file2244890
% set file_data [read $fp]
        this is
    one of
  example
   input file

% close $fp
% regsub -line -all {^\s+} $file_data {} output
4
% puts $output
this is
one of
example
input file

%
```

Answer (score 1):

There are higher-level commands in the Tcllib for this:

```
package require fileutil
package require textutil::trim

::fileutil::updateInPlace test_one.tcl ::textutil::trim::trimleft
```

After this invocation, the file contains the left-justified text.

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [textutil::trim](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/trim.html) package